# Identify the python module that you would need to calculate bond price?

Tags: python

Hi I need to understand what module do we import in order to calculate the bond prices using the concept of time value of money?

is it scipy or numpy?

Comment: Stack overflow is only for solving coding problem not even coding writing service. Write your own code by yourself & if you will stuck at any step we are here to help you. Thanks

Comment: @Ibnelaiq hi. sorry for that. just want to understand which is a module

Comment: @EdwardLau you could have searched the "Getting Started" of both of the modules

Comment: Hi @edward lau, we need a few details here. For example, what's the formula? What have you tried so far? Although Stack Overflow isn't a tutorial site, people here are helpful if you show that you've already had a go yourself, and got stuck. So please explain what you've tried and where you've looked-- then you'll get some helpful suggestions. Looks to me like `fractions` might sometimes be useful for bond prices-- and possibly `math`.

Answer (score 1):

The financial modules are included in `numpy`.
You can refer the link below.
[enter link description here](https://sushanthukeri.wordpress.com/2017/05/22/solving-time-value-of-money-problems-with-numpy/)
I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, `numpy` is a module. You can install `numpy` by using `pip install numpy` if you have not used any distributer linke **Anaconda**. **Anaconda** comes with `numpy` pre-installed.

Comment: a module is usually a single Python source file. That is not true of `numpy`. "`NumPy` is a library for the Python programming language, adding support for large, multi-dimensional arrays and matrices"-- Wikipedia